# Sumifs function in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

Hi my `SUMIFS` function is not adding up figures at all.  The `SUMIFS` formula I use is below:

```
=SUMIFS($O:$O,$A:$A,"distribution - reinv",$D:$D,">="&DATE(1,5,2020),$D:$D,"<="&DATE(31,5,2020))
```

The target cells have the correct information to calculate the amount but it is not adding up the data in cells D2083 and D2285 listed below.

cell A2083 says Distribution - reinv
cell D2083 (which is a merged cell with Column E) states 8/5/2020 (which is correct , it is 8th May 2020) but the date on the spreadsheet  shows as 5/8/2020 (incorrect, it is 5th August 2020 (American date format).

Another example shows cell D2285 (also a merged cell with column D) states 31/5/2020 (31st May 2020 which is correct) and the date on the spreadsheet shows as 31/5/2020 (also correct) however neither examples I have shown show the sum of the numbers in the cell with the `SUMIFS` formula.

What has happened? Is it something to do with the date format? I think all the formulas are correct. Hopefully it is a simple fix

Comment: Welcome to Super User,, please [edit] your post and add some sample data currently you are using, help us to test the formula U are using to fix it ☺

Comment: Hi Rajesh, how can I send you the file to look at

Comment: ,, check the edit link above , will open your question in Edit mode,, then you may copy & paste portion of sheet or use print screen from key board,, paste / paste in Paint brush,, select the useful portion,, make file and upload. Or [Chek this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) ☺

Comment: hi rajesh, it did not let me put an image in the edit mode, is there not a link that I can send an attachment of the file

Comment: ,, okay wait soon I'll post some solution with examples too.

Comment: Hi @Murray now check my post I've posted the solution along with the mistake you have committed, ☺

Answer (score 1):

**:Caveate:**

*Since OP is unable to upload sample data, therefore I've used data show below:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- To get Unique data list, an array (CSE) formula in cell AI12:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($AE$12:$AE$17,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($AI$11:$AI11,AE12:AE17),0)),"")}
  ```

*Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.*

**Note:**

- If you want to get SUM only for category Distribution, or any one only, then you may skip using the array formula.
- Formula in cell AJ12:

  ```
  =SUMIFS($AG$12:$AG$17,$AF$12:$AF$17,">=05/01/2020",$AF$12:$AF$17,"<=05/31/2020",$AE$12:$AE$17,"="&$AI12)
  ```

**N.B.**

- *Your mistake was using the wrong syntax for criteria,, `">="&DATE(1,5,2020)`.*
- *If you want to make the formula dynamic, better put Start & End date in any two cells, and use this one*,  `$AF$12:$AF$17,">="&AK11`.
- *Used date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`, you need to alter it according to the use in your TIME Zone or popular practice.*